# Does urllib.request use respect cache headers of HTTP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I can't find in the docs if `urllib.request.urlopen()` use the HTTP headers about caching like `Cache-Control: max-age`, `Expires:`, `Last-Modified:` and `ETag:` to optimize the retrieving of data. Does it?

And how it could be done, if `urllib` don't do it automatically.

Comment: use https://httpbin.org/get in `urlopen()` to get all headers send to this portal. And you will see if `urlopen()` uses cache headers.

Comment: documentation for [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html. See class [Request(..., headers={...})](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request)